# Java Script - Get property "innerText" from Table td

Tags: javascript, properties, gettext, innertext

I need to get the text that's written inside a td, but it always gives me an undefined.

This is my try of getting the text:

```
console.log($('USERvalue'+keykey).prop("innerText"));                                                                                                           
console.log($('td[id^="USERvalue"]').prop("innerText"));
```

Both are the same element. on the first one i target a specific one. In the second line i target several, because i just say the id should start with xy.
But both give me an undefined. If I'm correct that means that it finds the element but cant find any text.

This is the element i try to reach and get the text out of it:

```
for(let key = 0; key < GlobalVarUS2.length; key++){
    let temp = $("<tr><td id='USERvalue"+key+"' value='"+GlobalVarUS2[key]["pk_us_id"]+"'>"+GlobalVarUS2[key]["benutzername"]+"</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='CHBUSER"+key+"' style='size: 30px'></input></td></tr>");
    temp.appendTo("#table_user");
}
```

Ultimately I want to compare it to a string and if it is correct, do something. But first i need the text of the element.

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using $('td[id^="USERvalue"]').text() like a single element. But in real case it is returning multiple elements, So if you want text of all td then you have to process them in loop and you have to contain text in single variable which will be appended each time. for example:

```
var text="";
$.each($('td[id^="USERvalue"]'),function(k,v){
text += $(v).text();
});
console.log(text);
```